# Wxwidgets callback

Tags: c++, multithreading, events, callback, wxwidgets

i would like to add a callback function to a threaded function without freezing the main application.

Ex: when I click on a button, it start a threaded function. I wanna inform the user when the work is finish.

Thx

```
    cs functions;
    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, maFonction, (void*)&functions);
    //pthread_join(thread, NULL);
```

The pthread_join block the main application when waiting for the thread to finish. So how would I do it. Thx a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the thread in a detached state by calling `pthread_detach()` in the spawned thread, or when creating the thread in the main thread, set the pthread attributes for that thread to a detached state.  Now that the thread is detached, you won't need to call `pthread_join()` in the main thread. Next, in the spawned thread itself, before exiting the thread, push an event onto event queue of the WxWidgets object that spawned the thread in order to "announce" that the spawned thread has completed.  Finally, add an event handler for your thread-finishing event to your WxWidget object to handle the even the spawned thread will place on it's event queue.

For instance, you could create an event like `THREAD_FINISHED_EVENT` that you thread will push onto the event-queue of the object that will spawn the threads.  You code would look like the following:

```
wxCommandEvent event(THREAD_FINISHED_EVENT, GetId());

//"this" points to the parent WxWidgets object spawning the threads
//and allows you to access the "this" pointer in the handler
event.SetEventObject(this); 

//Send the event
this->AddPendingEvent(event);
```

The event itself will be processed in the main event thread of the WxWidget that installs the handler for the event. You'll just need to provide a handler for the WxWidget object, and define the event itself.  This can be done using the macro `DEFINE_EVENT_TYPE`, and then adding the following line to the constructor of the WxWidget object that will be spawning the threads themselves:

```
//myWxWidget::thread_handler is the handler for your thread ending events
Connect(widgetID, THREAD_FINISHED_EVENT, wxCommandEventHandler(myWxWidget::thread_handler))
```

Summing this all up, here's what some theoretical WxWidgets object class would look like:

```
//myWindowThreadClass.hpp
#include <wx/wx.h>
#include <wx/event.h>

extern expdecl const wxEventType THREAD_FINISHED_EVENT;

class myWindowThreadClass: public wxWindow
{
    public:
        myWindowThreadClass(wxWindow* parent, int id);

        //handler for the thread-ending event
        void thread_handler(wxCommandEvent& event);

        //pushes a thread event on the wxWidgets event-queue 
        //for myWindowThreadClass
        void send_thread_event();
};


//myWindowThreadClass.cpp
#include <myWindowthreadClass.h>
#include <pthread.h>

const wxEventType THREAD_FINISHED_EVENT = wxNewEventType();

void* thread_func(void* data)
{
    myWindowThreadClass* window_ptr = static_cast<myWindowThreadClass*>(data);

    //detach thread
    pthread_detatch(pthread_self());

    //... rest of thread function

    window_ptr->send_thread_event();

    return (void*)0;
}

myWindowThreadClass::myWindowThreadClass(wxWindow* parent, int id):
              wxWindow(parent, id)
{
    //enable the event handler
    Connect(id, THREAD_FINISHED_EVENT, wxCommandEventHandler(myWindowThreadClass::thread_handler));

    //create your threads
    pthread_t tid;
    for (int i=0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++)
    {
        pthread_create(&tid, NULL, thread_func, this);
    }

    //...do anything else needed to initialize object
}

void myWindowThreadClass::thread_handler(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    //handle the event
}

void myWindowThreadClass::send_thread_event()
{
    wxCommandEvent event(THREAD_FINISHED_EVENT, GetId());
    event.SetEventObject(this); 

    //Send the event ... import to use this function, as it will cause
    //the event to be processed in main-thread, not spawned child threads
    this->AddPendingEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: Much better than my answer! I'm a little too tired, can't think straight... :/

Answer (score 1):

Set a variable, eg. `xxx_is_done`, to `false` before starting the thread. And when the thread is done, the last thing it does is set `xxx_is_done` to `true`. Then just check the variable in the main event loop and call `pthread_join` on the thread when the variable is true and also set the variable back to `false` so you don't call `pthread_join` on the thread again.